# Accumulator Strings

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, accumulator

I have just started programming through a course offered at my school, so I do not know a lot right now. One of my homework questions requires me to use an accumulator string with a for loop. I have looked through my Python textbook and online for an explanation or example, but I have not found any that help me to understand how to apply it. I would just like an explanation on how to apply an accumulator string to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking to do - I use accumulators sometimes for uri encoding.

Create an empty string `mystring = ""` then run a loop let's say `for i in range(10):` add the string to the accumulator, something like `mystring += str(i)`

Answer (score 0):

def sum(lst):

```
accumulator = 0
for element in lst:
    accumulator += element
return accumulator
```

print('The sum  is ', sum(lst))